# Selectively converting float to whole number and decimals in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, type-conversion

I am reading data from multiple csv, applying some filters and merging them into a dataframe. The original data in csv is only numbers/fractions. Pandas is converting them into float. Thats OK but I need just 1 column to remain as it is. To convert that back to integer, I tried :

```
df['PRICE']=df['PRICE'].astype(int)
```

This works wonderful for whole numbers. However, this is also converting all decimals into whole numbers. Meaning, even

```
1162.50 --> 1162
```

I am looking to change it to something like :

```
1152.0  --> 1152
1216.50 --> 1216.5
1226.65 --> 1226.65
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can re-initialise the dataframe using the `pd.DataFrame` constructor with `dtype=object`:

```
print(df)

      Col1
0  1152.00
1  1216.50
2  1226.65

df = pd.DataFrame(df, dtype=object)
print(df)

      Col1
0     1152
1   1216.5
2  1226.65
```

Or, if it's just one column you want to convert, you can use the `pd.Series` constructor the same way:

```
df.Col1 = pd.Series(df.Col1, dtype=object)
print(df)

      Col1
0     1152
1   1216.5
2  1226.65
```

*Statutory Warning:* Having mixed types in a dataframe kills all the optimisation and speedup benefits that pandas/numpy offers for pure numeric types.

---

The method above outlines an approach to retain numeric properties, but if you want to save to CSV, you must convert to string and truncate, otherwise they will be coerced to floats when saving. This is how you'd do that:

```
out = df.astype(str).replace('\.0+$', '', regex=True)
print(out)

      Col1
0     1152
1   1216.5
2  1226.65

out.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Comment: thanks for the quick help. I can see the desired output in python dataframe. However when I write this modified df to csv using df.to_csv, it stores the values as float and not as object. Am I doing something wrong here ? Please guide.

Comment: If it helps, I need to maintain original formatting just for 1 column. Because, this has to be appended with another column. 

OK with rest of columns converting to float as data manipulation does not effect

Comment: @user3017186 Unfortunately, `df.to_csv` currently does not provide support for that. Columns are coerced to either int, string, or float.  If you'll see my edit, I've provided a workaround that involves string manipulation. Check it out, and do accept my answer if you think it helps.

Comment: this second edit solved the issue. Thanks for the update and also for showing me another way to solve issues using regex.